# KID PRIIPS regulation: PCA

Tags: pca, regulatory-formula

According to [KID/PRIIPS regulation](http://ec.europa.eu/finance/docs/level-2-measures/priips-delegated-regulation-2017-1473-annex_en.pdf) in your opinion

in which case should PCA (as from article 23) be used?

Just for structured products and bond-related products or also in other cases? 
Do you have practical examples where you would use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical uses of PCA in the industry are for modelling:

- Forward curves
- Yield curves

For the above cases, the first three Principal Components *typically* captures more than 95% of the curves moves, which makes it a powerful tool when it comes to curve modelling.

As Structured Products are a combination of an option component and a bond component, PCA would be used for the modelling of the bond component and more generally for bond-related products and, as I mentioned above, forward products.

Comment: Thanks for your answe. What do you think about insurance-related products?

Comment: For insurance-related products, I guess the focus is on credit risk and default probability. PCA is not relevant for such topics.

Comment: @Simons123 Also, feel free to mark the answer as "solved" if this is indeed the case ;) Thanks